# Coding third-order objects via second-order ones

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, reverse-math, computable-analysis

As is well-known, the language of second-order arithmetic only has variables for natural numbers and sets of natural numbers.  Higher-order objects, like functions on $\mathbb{R}$, have to be represented (aka 'coded').

For various reasons (including the foundational claims made in reverse math), it seems desirable that one can prove that 'basic' higher-order objects have codes/representations in 'relatively weak' systems.  (Note the subjective 'terms' meant to evade a flame war.)

To be absolutely clear, we assume at least Kohlenbach's base theory RCA$_0^\omega$ ([2]), which uses the language of all finite types.

As a positive example, one can show that (third-order) continuous functions on Cantor space have a representation/code in RCA$_0^\omega$ plus weak Koenig's lemma ([1]).

As negative examples, one needs rather stronger comprehension axioms (namely Kleene's $\exists^3$, which implies Z$_2$) to prove the following for third-order functions on $[0,1]$:

1. A Riemann integrable function on $[0, 1]$ can be represented by a code.
2. A lower semi-continuous function on a (countably or sequentially) compact and complete metric space can be represented by a code.
3. A Borel function on $[0, 1]$ can be represented by a code.
4. A function having bounded variation on $[0,1]$ can be represented by a code for a Baire class one function.
5. A function having bounded variation on [0, 1] has a code.

The coding in items 1-5 is found in e.g. the reverse math literature. The mathematical notions (bounded variation, Riemann integrable, ...) are given by their usual standard definition (that can be made in third-order arithmetic).

Finally, my question:

> What other notions have been 'coded' (in reverse math, computability theory, computable analysis, ...) besides the above that may be interesting to study?

Reference:

[1] U. Kohlenbach, Foundational and mathematical uses of higher types, Reflections on the foundations of mathematics, Lect. Notes Log., vol. 15, ASL, 2002, pp. 92–116.

[2] _____, Higher order reverse mathematics, Reverse mathematics 2001, Lect. Notes Log., vol. 21, ASL, 2005, pp. 281–295.

Comment: In computable analysis you can mechanically compute the coding for any construction expressible in higher-order logic, by computing the realizability interpretation of the construction. That is going to cover a lot of ground.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific?  For instance, say we have a covering  $\cup_{x\in [0,1]} B(x, F(x))$ of the unit interval for some fixed (possibly discontinuous) $F:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$.  What does this kind of construct get translated to?  Would e.g. $F$ be interpreted as a continuous function (like when using ECF)?

Comment: I don't think that these are provable things, since you can't even say that "A is a code for B" in a weak system if B is not a subset of integers. But you can declare "I will use A as a code for B", and prove that standard constructions of B work in those terms. So for the examples above, you would define operations on codes for addition and scalar multiplication, and prove the vector space axioms; you would prove that (codes for) bump functions exist for any (codes of) compact sets, etc. The big question is then: Can the weak system prove enough to make the declaration worthwhile?

Comment: You would say that $F \subseteq [0,1] \times \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and that $\forall x \in [0,1] \exists y \in \mathbb{R}^{+} . (x,y) \in F$. A realizer for this would be a computable map $t$ which for each *realizer* $r$ of some $x \in [0,1]$ computes a pair of realizers $t(r) = (u, v)$ such that $u$ realizes some $y \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $v$ realizes $F(x,y)$.

Comment: @Matt F.  I made my statements a little more specific.  So the idea (implied by the old version) is that we take usual standard 'epsilon-delta' definition of e.g. Riemann integration, formulated in the language of 3rd order arithmetic.  We then ask "how hard is it to show that each (third-order) Riemann integrable function has a code?"

Comment: @Andrej Bauer.  But what are the sets $F$? How are those given?

Comment: @ Matt F.  Fair point.  I of course meant "Coding third-order objects via second-order ones", which is perhaps less concise.

Comment: Is item 1 in your list equivalent to “there is a set $S$ of integers and a bijection between $S$ and the Riemann integrable functions”? That might work as a definition of “has a code”.

Comment: @Matt F.  The coding of Lebesgue integrable functions can be found in the final chapter of Simpson's excellent SOSOA, and the references therein.  I take this to cover the coding of Riemann integrable functions.

Comment: I see the definition in SOSOA X.1.12 but that does not provide an $RCA_0^\omega$ version of "A Riemann-integrable function can be represented by a code". It is fine to define (or as I said above, declare) that "a (code for) a measurable set $E$ with respect to $(X, \mu)$ is defined to be a measurable characteristic function $f\in L_1(X,\mu)$", but what statement expresses "has a code" in a form general enough that one can apply it to the other examples? In any case, I have given this a downvote, but I am open to removing that if the question is clarified.